# Flash CS5 font is largest part of the SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5, tlf

I'm transferring a project from CS4 to CS5 and (without any changes) my SWF file gets to be 10 times bigger. It was 7kb and now it's 77kb.  I generated a size report and it looks like the font is taking up most of the space. I haven't changed settings. I'm not sure why  font is taking up so much space.  Is there a way around this? Here is my size report:

```
Font Name            Bytes         Characters
-----------------    ----------    ----------
_sans                        12    
MilkyWell                   317    .blsu
Calibri-Bold Bold         75960    %.0123456789
```

As you can see Calibri-Bold is taking up 75kb and I only have 12 characters in it.

**update:** I removed the Calibri font from my project. It brought it down from 77kb to 3kb.

Answer (score 1):

The calibri bold font is about 900k, so size seems reasonable to me.

I tested it on CS5 and got

```
Font Name            Bytes         Characters
-----------------    ----------    ----------
Calibri-Bold Bold         74514    %.0123456789
```

any chance that your CS4 project was using device fonts?

Calibri is an MS font and comes default on all windows machines since Vista, not sure about osX. I think you have them installed if you install any of the ms office suites, or install manually.

Comment: How can I tell if my project is using device fonts? I saved my original FLA project as XFL so and searched in PublishSettings.xml and found a node <DeviceFont>0</DeviceFont>  So since I haven't changed any settings, it looks like my CS4 project did not use device fonts. But good point.

Comment: when you click on a textfield, in the properties you can select it under aliasing, but I'm noticing that flash still embeds the font. It's bizarre.

Comment: This seems to be happening with calibri, but I cannot get it to do the same with other fonts

Comment: I've tried converting it to TLF and size drops from 77kb to 50kb. Still big but a little improvement.

Comment: Is it possible that it's trying to load fonts at runtime from external location? Here is what my Action Script 3.0 settings look like -http://i.imgur.com/zIspg.png  And if it doesn't find them it embeds them?

Comment: I doubt it. It only happens with calibria (maybe a few others that I haven't seen) can you use a different font?